# Running php page as background without cronjob

Tags: php

First greetings to all. Secondly I'm sorry I don't provide source or something but it is because simply I don't have yet.

I just confronted the following issue and need some help and some starting points.

I have a form which submit some data in mysql and save status `pending(0)` and is working great. What I wonder how can be done is after user submit the form how to trigger another php file which must do following actions on background

- pull data from api periodically and check for status changes. Once
  the status is changed to `Not Pending` to update database with new
  status.

How can be done this? And to be more fun (for me) this script will update orders, so there would be multiple orders.. Also I'm limited from my hosting provider to not use cronjobs and js..

Comment: Read about Gearman

Comment: Just simply include the other php page in your code and invoke its functionality. Pls note that your provider cannot prevent you from using client side js.

Comment: Thanks to both for the comments. @Shadow `Just simply include the other php page in your code and invoke its functionality.` Once is invoked how to make it to work continuously? What if user close the browser.. will stop, right?

Comment: It does not need to run continuously. You just run it whenever you change the status.

Comment: I don't understand. How the second script which is invoked will know that the status is changed in the API if API  doesn't push anything? I get the information with simple curl. As I understand the problem this file which will check and update should be triggered somehow when there are changes on api side